# Who is the elf from ESO trailers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In ESO most trailers is featured an elf (Bosmer I guess? Despite the clothing that is Altmer). In the earlier trailers (2014) I thought "heroes" were not characters from the game, but here (Summerset trailer) the cat is pretty obviously Razum-dar, so maybe she is a character in game too:

So who is she?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She's an Altmer returning from the original cinematic trailer series for the base game (she's technically the only survivor of the three heroes, if you ignore the Nord's implied imprisonment in Coldharbour). Similar to the original trailers, she's acting as a stand-in replacement for a potential player character, similar to how the Warden in the Morrowind cinematic trailer worked with Naryu (while also representing the new class introduced with Morrowind).

And yes, she's supposed to be an Altmer, not a Bosmer. The Khajiit is indeed Razum-dar, and the other party members are just red shirts without red shirts.

Comment: I never realized that the Khajitt is Rasum-dar, and he's one of my favorite supporting characters...

Comment: @kittenchops Spoiler: The Collector's Edition's Art Book is actually Razum-dar's Journal (or more specific a collection/report for Her Majesty).

Comment: @Mario:( For some reason I'm missing that from the box... or is for the Summerset Collector Edition (I have the original game collector, expansions standard)? And... Raz rocks :). Only character that may be better is Naryu.

Comment: @zozo I'm talking about the Summerset CE.